# Why ChakraUI provider cause react-spring/parallax not shown

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui, conflicting-libraries

This is just some newbies question, but I'm very confused. What I know is Chakra UI just some style applied to the component. But I found that I can't use react-spring parallax with ChakraUI. I have done some research and found nothing about how to make it work.

I have a normal working React-spring Parallax website, but when I apply  `<ChakraProvider> </ChakraProvider>`, everything disappear. No error shown, but my parallax effect is disappear too

Anyone know how to apply or use react-spring, or any component that 'conflict' with ChakraProvider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error. Seems like react-spring/parallax have some conflict with chakra ui style. At the end, I use  Framer Motion because it is compatible with Chakra UI

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the **<React.StrictMode>** wrapper from index.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).